# How to install kb* Windows updates with batch script if it's not installed already?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have tons of FortiClient clients that I need to install on individual computers, each client has it's own PC at home and some of them have Windows 7 32-bit. (Yes, I even saw an XP one.)

I've managed to create a batch script that will install the free FortiClient with all the configuration inside by importing the registry key at the beginning of the script and it's working great, but on Windows 7 32-bit, you can install it only if you have some Windows updates installed before.

So, I've came to a conclusion that I can create a batch file that will check if the KB is installed or not.

So here is the code:

```
@echo off
Pushd "%~dp0"
wmic qfe get hotfixid | find "KB3033929"
if %errorlevel% neq 1 ECHO KB3033929 Found
if %errorlevel% equ 1 ECHO KB3033929  NOT Found, installing KB3033929
(
    wusa .\Windows6.1-KB3033929-x86.msu /quiet /norestart
)
regedit /s .\korona.reg
msiexec.exe /qb /i "%~dp0FortiClient.msi"  /norestart INSTALLLEVEL=3
pause
```

But each time I am running the code, I am getting an error that the syntax is wrong, even though I run only the line with the `wusa` command.

PS: If you have any other ideas, this would be great - I don't want to use PowerShell.

Comment: I've used the `wmic qfe` command in the past and find it did not list some updates despite them being installed.  Seems that if Windows `Disk Cleanup` tool has been run with the `Windows Update Cleanup` option selected, it removes the KBs from the list but if you run that KB installer it will tell you is already installed.  Perhaps any easier way is just attempt to install the KB on all Win7 32bit machines it detects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` syntax is wrong:

```
if %errorlevel% equ 1 ECHO KB3033929  NOT Found, installing KB3033929

(
  wusa .\Windows6.1-KB3033929-x86.msu /quiet /norestart

)
```

should probably be

```
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
  ECHO KB3033929  NOT Found, installing KB3033929
  wusa .\Windows6.1-KB3033929-x86.msu /quiet /norestart
)
```

3 Months later: in the meantime, this KB is superseeded several times. So actually KB3033929 might not be installed, but a successor is that prevents KB3033929 from installing (which is ok from a technical point of view as the successor includes the function, but ruins your logic).

[Source and workaround](https://www.navossoc.com/2017/03/how-to-check-if-kb3033929-or-similar-is-installed-for-sure/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I admit that my batch scripting skills are not so well :) thank you very much !, i can add the rest of the code to the end of the script and it'll work right?